# How do you get the number of comments made by user across all pull-requests in an organization in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

we are looking to generate some productivity metrics in Bitbucket and its getting very hard to get this data.
I know we have to use the api in some way, but am not seeing how do you get this in the right way.

Basically, we need all the comments made per user (for all users) across any pull request in any repo in an organization. Does anyone know how to do this ?